# First time deploying a serverless solution to Azure and I'm a bit stuck

Tags: azure, sql

I'm new to the Azure environment, usually I've just deployed personal React Apps to Heroku, but I need to build an app and deploy it entirely in the Azure environment.

I wonder how to tie the following together:

- React SPA deployed on Azure (completed)
- Functions App - trying this without the Azure API management if possible (will only have or two Functions)
- Azure hosted SQL Database.

I'm looking for anything that provides a totally linked example. The end goal is just a simple webapp, auth'd via entra id / active user directory, with basic crud operations to the database for some users and read only for others.

Any guidance?